# Combining multiple functions of derivatives

Tags: matlab

Working with trying to make an Olver's method, my code is working however I want to try and combine the 3 functions into multi output function with use of diff() but i'm struggling to manipulate the inputs without jeopardizing outputs.

```
% Defining the function in the equation f(x)=0
function y = f(x)
y = x-exp(1/x);
end

% Defining the derivative of the function in the equation f(x)=0
function y = fd(x)
y = 1+exp(1/x)/(x^2);
end

% Defining the second derivative of the function in the equation f(x)=0
function y = fdd(x)
y = exp(1/x)*(2*x+1)/(x^4);
end
```

Comment: could you specify an example for an input and a wanted output?

Comment: In this case the input would be 1.5 initially and would change based on the output converging to a root. Olver's method is a more complex Newton-Raphson method that uses the second derivative as well as the first.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear but having all these as a single function (with the use of Symbolic Toolbox) can be done as follows:

```
function [y1, y2, y3] = getDerivatives(a)
syms f(x)
f(x) = x-exp(1/x);
fd = diff(f,x);
fdd = diff(f,x,2);
y1 = double(f(a));
y2 = double(fd(a));
y3 = double(fdd(a));
end
```

and you can run it as follows:

```
[y1, y2, y3] = getDerivatives(1)

y1 =

   -1.7183


y2 =

    3.7183


y3 =

   -8.1548
```